# How to print for loop results in next next rows in table

Tags: javascript, html

I have forloop which run and give some result upto X limit.

I'm trying to print those results in table rows but its just print all those result in same table row i want those results on next next rows.

My sample Code

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>..</th>
    <th>..</th>
    <th>..</th>
  <thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="details">
    </tr>
  <tbody>
<table>

<script>
  for(i=0; i<20; i++){
   //   ....code....
    document.getElementById('details').innerHTML +="<td>"+ name +"</td>";
  }
</script>
```

Actual Code

```js
for(let i=0; i< len; i++){
  for(let j=0; j<len1; j++){
    if(data['markets'][i]['baseMarket'] == data['assets'][j]['type'] && data['markets'][i]['quoteMarket'] == "inr") { 

      name     = data['assets'][j]['name'];
      symbol   = data['assets'][j]['type'];
      currency = data['markets'][i]['quoteMarket'];
      price    = data['markets'][i]['buy'];

      document.getElementById('details').innerHTML += "<td>"+name+"</td>";
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, the element you get by id is already a row. You then attempt to add more rows inside this row, which the browser doesn't understand, and will instead skip the row elements and look at the td tag. If you remove the row in your HTML and move the id to the table body, the rest of your code should work.

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>..</th>
    <th>..</th>
    <th>..</th>
  <thead>
  <tbody id="details">

  <tbody>
<table>

<script>
    for(let i=0; i< 10; i++){
        document.getElementById('details').innerHTML += "<tr><td>"+i+"</td></tr>";
    }

</script>
```

See [this JSFiddle for a demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lwhv24ng/)